# How can we print id of a UIElement that has been generated in Main.storyboard sourcecode

Tags: ios

I want to print id="DDH-zU-J2t"(got from Main.storyboard sourcecode).
How can I print the id property of any element in console of XCode?

Comment: The identifier in the storyboard does not make it into the object when the storyboard scene is instantiated.

Comment: may I know what the purpose you want to get that

Comment: I want to check the id of the element.